# Microsoft Azure invalid app registration error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to make an app for linking minecraft account to discord and followed that API (oauth2 section) https://mojang-api-docs.gapple.pw/authentication/msa

Even tho I did everything correct, i keep getting error:

```
data: {

ath: '/authentication/login_with_xbox',

errorMessage: 'Invalid app registration, see https://aka.ms/AppRegInfo  for more information'

 }
```

Here is my app configration:

```
"azure" : {
        "client_id": "0bcbd41f-e785-45e4-b63c-3a68a0297007",
        "client_secret": "dont wanna post it here",
        "redirect_uri": "https://magiauth-verification.onrender.com/"
    }
```

I tried to remake an app and change supported account types (Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox), Personal Microsoft accounts only etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turns out that Mojang refuses new apps now, unless you register on the following link. After 3-4 weeks they responded to me via mail and my app finally works! Just complete the form and wait!

Good luck